# Cordova Camera Plugin returns green pictures Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, camera, windows-phone-8.1, cordova-plugins

Very strange behaviour: after takinf a 2nd or third picture using cordova camera plugin returned picture is green and about 200kb while normally about 2 mb. When taking more 'green' pictures application crashes and default camera screen becomes green untill phone is restarted.

Tryed different parameters like getting url instead of base64, different picture sizes - no luck.

This is reproduced on Nokia Lumia 520, but Microsoft Lumia 535 allowes to take about 6 pictures. While android works fine.

Code looks like:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
});
```

Tryed to use capture plugin result is the same.

Comment: Gettings the error dump from the phone says: **Exception Code 0xC0000194** (very meaningful message).

Dev windows phone says: "0xC0000194 NonResponsiveProcess A process became unresponsive for an unknown reason."

Comment: I am also using a Nokia Lumia 520. Hard reset your phone to resolve this quickly. I don't think there's a way to prevent this. Even upgrading to cordova-camera 2.0.0 this issue still sometimes happens. It's possibly overheating.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
camera: {
    pictureSource: "UNDEFINED",
    destinationType: "UNDEFINED",
    cameraInitialize: function () {
        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        cameraOptions = { quality: 50, allowEdit: true, destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL, correctOrientation: true }
        galleryOptions = { quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY }
    },
    getPicture: function (cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution so far (per microsoft support) is to hard reset your phone. 
I have an ancient Lumia running windows phone 8.1 and it is having the same issue in my app.

I actually *think* that the device is overheating.

Also things you should do to help avoid camera issues in your WP app:

- Assuming you use cordova, check if the video object has the maximum
  z-index and check if it isn't stacking under your application.
- If you also use angular, some button types fire ng-click twice on IE and so the camera opens twice.
- Implement cordova-camera-plugin 2.0.0  which fixes things like
  double-tapping in the camera and making it crash

I hope this helps you in your *painful* quest.