# Cordova Camera Plugin do not work on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Im trying to user de Cordova Camera Plugin in a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I already use the same plugin with the same code implementation on Android and iOS, but when a try on Windows Phone 8.1 the app crash and reset.

```
function getImageFromLib() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
    exibeAlerta("Nenhuma foto foi selecionada.");
},{
    quality: 50, 
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    allowEdit: true,
}
                           );}
```

The upload callback is a empty function, but the app is still crashing.

When a try on Windows 8 (desktop) everythig works fine!

Can some one help-me?

Comment: Have you also tried to run your app on different wp8 devices? May be its a hardware issue, as it was stated(overheating) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416719/cordova-camera-plugin-returns-green-pictures-windows-phone-8-1).

Comment: Thanks for your help, @blauharley.

I have tried only on Lumia 435. Do you know anything about an issue on this hardware?

Comment: Sorry but no, I've also read some articals about the camera plugin and that it causes problems especially on luma devices. I would recommand to try your app on another device, right now it seems that the camera plugin tries to access some hardware component that this device can not support(so in this case no overheating problem). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help again!